# It is May 12th, 1959, when I'm introduced to Janey

Tags: tense

Is it possible to use the present tense along with an adverbial of the past time?

> (1) It is May 12th, 1959, when I'm introduced to Janey.

This is a transcript of the movie "Watchmen." And you can hear the movie sound [here](http://movie-sounds.org/superhero-movie-sound-clips/sound-clips-from-watchmen-2009/it-is-may-12th-1959-when-i-m-introduced-to-janey).

Is it really natural or even grammatical to use the present tense "am" along with the adverbial "May 12th, 1959" as in (1)?

Since it's a cleft sentence, you should be able to change it to:

> (2) I'm introduced to Janey on May 12th, 1959.

OR

> (3) On May 12th, 1959, I'm introduced to Janey.

If (1)'s natural, how about (2) and (3)?

### EDIT

I'd like to make it clear that I do understand the use of the present tense for the past time in a narrative setting. The question really is not about the use of the present tense itself but the use of the present tense along with the past-time adverbial.

Is it okay to use the present tense along with the past-time adverbial when you describe the past time in a narrative setting?

Comment: Related SE topic: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139986/past-present-tense-when-telling-a-story-in-spoken-english (doesn't answer the question fully but has some info on the use of present to describe past events)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narration#Narrative_time: The narrative tense or narrative time determines the grammatical tense of the story; whether in the past, present, or future.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that "Watchmen" [sic] is a film with a very particular mood throughout. Although set in the past, the language throughout is immediate; present tense. The author is trying to bring the audience into the time; not through flashbacks or memories, but as though you were there, then.

The whole mood is retro, but even more so. It's very powerful in that respect (not to mention many others...)

Comment: So in that sort of "Watchmen" mood, are (2) and (3) also natural?

Comment: (2) and (3) are not as evocative of the period as the original sentence. Watch a few postwar private detective movies and you will see that this type of phrasing is common: like entries in a private detective's notebook.

Comment: @JavaLatte So are you saying that (2) and (3) are not natural or even grammatical?

Comment: @JK2: that's not what JavaLatte is saying. Understand "not as evocative of the period" to mean, "does not contribute so well to the retro mood of the film". It doesn't mean that they grammatically fail to specify the time of the introduction to Janey. They're both grammatical and IMO about as natural-sounding as the original. JavaLatte is only saying that (1) is most fitting for the style/genre that Watchmen is using.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for answering. Since you say that it's grammatical to use the present tense with an adverbial of the past time, could you show me some examples of such sentences? Preferably taken from a grammar book or something of that nature.

Comment: @JK2: I don't have anything to hand because I only speak the language, I don't study it closely. From that perspective I don't see it as any different from using any adverb of time with the present tense. It's not a special construction, just combining two uncontroversial things. In fact I don't see how the fact the time is in the past can make a difference to whether it's grammatical: whether it's *true*, maybe. Why do you expect (2) to be different from "I'm talking to JK2 on the 21st July"?  If I'm missing a subtlety that needs explanation then it's probably beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Similarly it's not ungrammatical to use a future time with the past tense. "It was 21st July 2017 when I paid that bill, stop asking me for the money", isn't ungrammatical. It's just false! It also rings a bit odd, since you'd normally say "I paid that bill on 21st July 2017", but the first way emphasises my memory of that having been the date at the time I made the payment.

Comment: @SteveJessop "I'm talking to JK2 on the 21st July," I get it, assuming that the time of speaking falls on the 21st July. But normally you'd say "I **was** talking to JK2 on the 21st July" if you were speaking it on the 22nd July. No?

Comment: @SteveJessop Now, as for "It was 21st July 2017 when I paid that bill, stop asking me for the money" or "I paid that bill on 21st July 2017", aren't you treating the future date (21st July 2017) as if it were a date in the past? Otherwise, I don't think I understand either of the sentences.

Comment: As @SteveJessop says, the two sentences are grammatically correct. The *historical present* is a way of creating a narrative style: it's not intended to be*natural*.  For example, when somebody says "A penguin walks into a bar... ", I know from the narrative style that they are starting to tell a joke. Similarly the narrative style of (1) tells me that it's likely to be set in the 40's or 50's: (2) seems very prosaic, and (3) seems like an attempt at a narrative style, but does not give me any clues what style the writer intended.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is okay to use the present tense along with past-time adverbials when you describe past time in a narrative setting. It is the [historical present](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present). It can also be called the storytelling present and narrative present. Jokes also often  use the present tense. The use of the present tense gives the sense of immediacy.

Such uses can include adverbials of time (which talk about past time) treated in the present tense:

> **Yesterday**, John goes into a bar. He orders a drink. He begins a conversation before leaving. He forgets to pay.

Source" [As Time Goes by: Tense and Universal Grammar - Page 199](https://books.google.com/books?id=sIqcwHjIypgC&pg=PA199&dq=%22Yesterday,+John+goes+into+a+bar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf89emhYXOAhUD3SYKHdGbCzcQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Yesterday%2C%20John%20goes%20into%20a%20bar%22&f=false)

> "**It is a bright summer day in 1947.** My father, a fat, funny man with beautiful eyes and a subversive wit, is trying to decide which of his eight children he will take with him to the county fair. My mother, of course, will not go. She is knocked out from getting most of us ready: I hold my neck stiff against the pressure of her knuckles as she hastily completes the braiding and the beribboning of my hair. . . ."

Alice Walker, "Beauty: When the Other Dancer Is the Self." In Search of Our Mothers' Gardens: Womanist Prose. Harcourt Brace, 1983. (Cited [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/histpreterm.htm).)

and

> **Two weeks before Christmas** Malachy and I come home from school in a heavy rain and when we push in the door we find the kitchen empty...

from *Angela's Ashes*, by Frank McCourt ([cited here](http://grammar.about.com/od/shortpassagesforanalysis/a/mccourtangelastyle.htm).)

Comment: The Wikipedia reference you cited doesn't have any example sentence where the historical present is accompanied by a past-time adverbial. Could you corroborate your answer with some authoritative source?

Comment: @JK2 Edited to include three examples. The first is from a book published by MIT Press, the second from actual uses in writing.

Answer (score 1):

- I decide to answer this question at 11:26 AM on July 21, 2016.
- Some time having elapsed, it is 11:27 AM when I write the second
  sentence.
- At 11:28 AM I conclude my third sentence.

All of these statements are grammatically sound, factually accurate, and fully understandable at the time I make them. The date and times are present-time adverbials, as they describe the present as I write them. The sentences do feel a bit affected (and thus unnatural by one definition of the word), as I am not in the habit of stream-of-consciousness, real-time narration of my life.

I imagine that someone else reading my statements, at some time in the future, might also be struck by a sense of "unnaturalness" since by then, the **present-time adverbials of my first three sentences will *appear to be* past-time adverbials** (as, in fact, they already do, as I write this at 11:31 AM). Despite any sense of dislocation when read in the future, this sentence will still be as grammatically sound as when I first write it at 11:33 AM.

These "flexible" adverbials of time are also used outside of true, real-time present tense: writers using the present tense can "project" the narrative voice into the past, using a date or time which would be "past" in the real-world present as a present-time adverbial in their constructed present.

When I search for the phrase ["It's noon when I" in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m%20sitting%20here%22#tbm=bks&q=%22It%27s%20noon%20when%20I%22), I find many, many recent examples of the use of the present tense with a time stamp. This suggests to me that it is a natural construction for those who are comfortable with narrating in the eternal now. However, adverbials of time that are *inherently* "past" are not common: when I look for ["it's yesterday when I"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it%20is%20yesterday%22#tbm=bks&q=%22it%27s%20yesterday%20when%20I%22) I only get three hits, none of which really fit the present-tense narration style.

Note that the sense of wrongness associated with this style can abate as one gets used to reading the literary present-tense; it has been [used for some time to *describe* fiction](http://vanderbilt.edu/writing/manage/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Literary%20present%20tense.pdf), and in recent years this ersatz-real-time style is becoming [more popular as a device for *writing* fiction](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/nov/21/rise-of-the-present-tense-in-fiction-hilary-mantel). Although its use in narrative [is still controversial](http://www.salon.com/2010/09/22/present_tense/) stylistically (and I personally dislike it intensely), I cannot find complaints that it is *ungrammatical* (though, of course, it is difficult to prove a negative).

---

TL;DR: The present tense ***can* be used  with time adverbials that are *ambiguous*** (changing from future to present to past as time passes) **such as specific dates and times**. However, it generally is not used with *inherently past*-time adverbials such as *yesterday* or *last year*. Your sentences are examples of the former.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the links. It's interesting to note that the Vanderbilt writing guide recommends using the past tense for those sentences having a past adverbial and using the present tense for those not having a past adverbial, be the past adverbial _inherently past_ or not.